# HTML email message body with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

Without subclassing UIActivity, is it possible to use UIActivityViewController (UIActivityTypeMessage) to share a html message via the Mail app?

When I passed the HTML as NSString, the body shows the html tags (e.g. ) in the message body which is not what I want.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the string you pass into the activity includes `<html`.  UIKit's internal UIMailActivity class explicitly checks for the presence of `<html` to determine if the message is HTML or plain text.

```
[r12 rangeOfString:@"<html" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:0x0];
```

Note that while UIActivity is documented that it can send HTML messages, this exact trigger mechanism isn't part of the API contract.  Technically, it could break in future versions.