# Mail with HTML contents / UIActivityViewController

Tags: html, ios, email, swift3, uiactivityviewcontroller

In order to unify the way I share information from one of my iOS apps, I am trying to use UIActivityViewController. So good so far, except for one detail. I cannot cleanly handle the case of a mail with HTML contents. I read a couple of post on the subject, but nothing satisfying.

Here comes the question, how do I cleanly handle the case of a mail with HTML contents?

Would it be just better in such a case to give up using UIActivityViewController and go back to the classical MFMailComposeViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSArray* dataToShare = @[html];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[keyWindow addSubview: self.view];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

You could also write the HTML source to a local file, e.g., `my_mail_message.html`, then build an `NSURL` object with that file, e.g., `[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://my_mail_message.html"]`, and then use that `NSURL` object as an element of the `activityItems` array that you feed to `initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities`. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is much more complicated than just using the old MFMailComposeViewController. So that basically means there is no way to cleanly handle HTML mail contents with UIActivityViewController.

Comment: You might try this answer. It is from 2013 but I just tried it (June 2019) in Swift and it works.  Just make sure your message is wrapped with <html>...</html>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695877/html-email-message-body-with-uiactivityviewcontroller